# Синхронизация nullable переменной между потоками

Tags: c#, многопоточность, синхронизация

Имеется *nullable* переменная, к которой требуется доступ из разных потоков. Например, `int?`. Какой способ синхронизации такой переменной стоит использовать в C#? Самый прямолинейный - обернуть всё это в `lock`. Было предположение, что справится и `volatile`, но он c *nullable* не умеет.

Что делать, если нужно скопировать это значение локально, писать функцию (лямбду), тело которой обёрнуто в `lock`? Копирование в первую очередь для того, чтобы уменьшить время блокировки между потоками.

Comment: Для синхронизации нужно использовать `lock`. Другие методы допускается использовать, если вам нужна экстремальная оптимизация, и вы **очень хорошо** понимаете, что делаете. (В частности, если у вас нету _зависимых_ переменных.)

Comment: Я обычно переписываю алгоритмы, чтобы у них вовсе не было разделяемого состояния. Таким образом, необходимость в синхронизации отпадает сама собой.

Comment: А зачем лямбда? `int? local; lock (mutex) local = shared; // используем local`

Comment: Хотя конечно зависит от точного смысла того, что именно вам надо.

Comment: @VladD я хотел совместить с инициализацией, потому и о (лямба) функции подумал. Сложно не использовать разделяемого состояния, когда нужно это состояние передавать.

Comment: Хм. Сложно, но можно. Вот простой частный случай: если нужно подсчитать количество запятых в тексте, мы делим его на части, у каждой часть подсчитывает локальное количество (в отдельном потоке), а потом мы их собираем и складываем. Разделяемая переменная оказывается не нужна.

Comment: Расскажите лучше о вашей более общей задаче. (А мы все налетим, и скажем, что так делать не надо, что потоки отстой, и нужно переходить на async/await.)

Comment: @VladD можно, конечно, взять готовое значение по окончании работы потока. Но в моём случае поток осуществляет циклический опрос данных по сети и эти данные нужно отображать в гуйне.

Comment: Если нужно доставить значение в UI-поток, используйте (в WPF) `await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => UpdateUI(newValue));`. Синхронизация для этого тоже не нужна.

Comment: Синхронизация уже не в моде :) Я стараюсь обходиться без неё.

Comment: @VladD `await` у меня, кажется, отсутствует. Хотя, это же надо .Net 4.5 иметь, да? Проект под WinForms, вяло текущий и какие-то существенные изменения вносить туда нежелательно.

Comment: Ну, если WinForms и старый фреймворк, то тогда `form.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => UpdateUI(newValue)));`. Действует по принципу fire and forget. Если нужно дождаться окончания обновления UI, то `Invoke` вместо `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: @VladD это на каждый элемент гуйни надо свою функцию типа `UpdateUI` в формочке иметь?

Comment: Ну я бы сделал у формы одну или нескольку таких функций, и она уж пускай занимается обновлением UI. Это как бы её ответственность.

Comment: @alexolut, await можно нормально завести в 4.0, надо подключить просто библиотеку MS. А ниже 4.0 опускаться смысла нет - на XP ставится 4.0

Comment: @alexolut, чойта Вас в чате нет? Локализаторы требуются, а их нет.

Comment: @Other чат для этого не нужен. Достаточно Меты и дёргать рычаг по результатам.

Comment: @alexolut, нам без Вас скучно! :)

Comment: @Other ну, можно пофлагать кого-нибудь для веселья :)

Comment: @alexolut, меня уже пофлагали какие-то нехорошие люди. Не парьтесь, приходите обратно, кусать, вроде как, никто не хочет.